# How can I monitor data speeds on a Thunderbolt 3 port?

Tags: io, thunderbolt

I am using a Thunderbolt 3 hub with two 4k monitors, Time Capsule, USB, and speakers, connected to it from my my MacBook Pro. This is all done with a single Thunderbolt 3 cable. Is it possible to monitor the amount of data passing through that port/cable in real time?

Comment: You are mixing 2 different things - I have the same setup as you (minus the speakers) - and it is one thing to monitor the data transfer amount per second vs the speed of the transfer. Which do you need?

Comment: Ah, I see. I am really looking for the data transfer amount per second. But now that you bring the speed, I would be curious, but it's not needed.